# What is a word for "subconscious agreement"?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Sam usually didn't let people in his room. But because Rachel was so neat and organized, Sam ***[allowed her without ever talking about it]*** her to work up in his small room when he was out of the house.

Comment: Sam ***didn't think twice*** about letting her work...

Comment: What does "talking about" have to do with "subconscious"? Isn't it supposed to be "thinking"? How could it be an agreement? You need to explain what you are looking for in more details.

Comment: Do you mean 'unspoken' agreement?

Answer (score 2):

It's not one word, but you could use the adverb *tacitly* with a following verb such as *agree*, *consent* or *allow*:

> Sam usually didn't let people in his room. But because Rachel was so neat and organized, Sam **tacitly** allowed her to work up in his small room when he was out of the house.

Or perhaps:

- Sam and Rachel had a tacit agreement that she could work in his room when he was out of the house.

Comment: And there are alternatives to "allowed" -- "suffered", "permitted", "tolerated", "endured" -- which can add a sense of how much comfort Sam has in the situation.

Comment: @MετάEd Yes, indeed! Hence the "such as" etc. :)